# Is there a way to determine maximum rpm for axial compressor due to material limitations?

Tags: jet-engine, compressor

I'm looking for RPM to Stress relation to determine maximum rotational speed that compressor/turbine blades can have without undergoing deformation due to centrifugal tensile stress.

I've come come across this relation but I'm not sure if its correct one:
$$ v_t = \sqrt{\frac{\sigma}{\frac{1}{2} \times \rho \times \left[ 1 - \left( \frac{\Omega_h}{\Omega_t} \right)^2 \right]}} $$
where:

- $\sigma$ is the stress (tensile) of the material
- $\rho$ is the material density
- $v_t$ is the rotational speed of Rota
- $\Omega_h / \Omega_t$ is the Hub-Tip ratio